# How can I show $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

I would like to prove that if $\gamma \in C^0_c(]a,b[,\mathbb{R})$ and $\epsilon >0$ then we can find $f \in C^{\infty}_c(]a,b[,\mathbb{R})$ and $K \geq 0$ such that $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$ and such that for every $x \in [a,b]$ where $\gamma'(x)$ exists then $\|\gamma'(x)-f(x)\|<K\epsilon$.

I tried using Stone theorem but I cannot control the condition of the derivative.

More in general, if $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is open, is it true that $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C^0(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Have you tried using cutoff functions?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I think I do not know them. Could you explain it?

Comment: See the section on Convolution and Regularization in Brezis's book. Proposition 4.21 is what you need.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Thank you!

Comment: You are the most welcome :)

Comment: To control the domains one can use mollifiers (bump functions) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier.  Also, using translation of mollifiers and the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, you can show that they form a dense sense on each each $C_K$, $K$ compact,  were $C_K$ is the space of all continuous functions with supposed contained in $K$.